# How can i remove the text parameter from grid view control on runtime through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TypeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to remove this attribute `Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'` programmatically on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the `RowDatabound` as shown below :

```
  protected void GridViewName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
              //Hide the Textbox
               TextBox txtboxtobehidden= 
            (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtboxtobehidden");
               txtboxtobehidden.Visible = false;    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // your error Code
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I want the textbox the thing is i only want to remove the attribute

Comment: @TusharPrithviraj remove attribute in the sense , you want to empty that text box ?

Comment: i want to generate an empty row in the begining and bind data if the condition is true. data bind is happening but for new empty row it gives error  that it could not find "Type" as type is not there, i want to remove Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' for empty row and assign Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' bind when reading and  binding the data to grid view.

Comment: @TusharPrithviraj for that you don't need to remove the attribute , you need to check a condition in `RowDatabound` whether the `Type` exists or not , if it doesn't exist , try to clear the textbox value as follows : `txxtboxtobehidden.Text = string.empty`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid null exception on binding you can choose one option below:

- You can change `Text` attribute in **HTML Markup** like:

  ```
  Text='<%# Eval("Type").Tostring() == string.Empty ? "NA" : Eval("Type") %>'
  ```
- Or, you can do it in **Code-Behind** like in `RowDataBound` event:

  ```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          // find your textbox control in gridview
          TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtboxtobehidden");

          if(tb.Text == "") 
          {
              // To remove Text attribute
              tb.Attributes.Remove("Text");

              // tb.Text = "NA";
          }
      }
  }
  ```